# contact form in PHP

Tags: php, forms, email, post

I have a contact form in PHP that gives me some errors.This is the code I use:

```
$message=$_POST["name"]."\r\n".$_POST["email"]."\r\n".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n".$_POST["subject"]."\r\n".$_POST["message"];

smtpmailer('ali_n_claudiu@yahoo.com', 'mailinteraction@gmail.com', 'Improve Mediehus Aarhus', 'From contact form', $message);
```

My problem is that when I load the page for the first time it gives me errors regarding the "$message=..." row for all the strings:

> Notice: Undefined index: name in D:\xampp\htdocs\interaction\contact.php on line 56
>   Notice: Undefined index: email in D:\xampp\htdocs\interaction\contact.php on line 56
>   and same error for phone, subject and message.

after I submit the contact form, I don't receive anymore errors.

also when I load the page for the first time, it sends and empty e-mail to the desired address

last problem is that even if I use a javascript code for receiving a pop-up message after submiting the email, I don't receive any.

I read other posts and tried different ideas that you gave other people with similar errors, but without any result.

Answer (score 1):

You should make use of the **[`isset`](http://www.php.net/function.isset)** construct to check for variables before assigning.

```
if(isset($_POST["name"]))
{
$name = $_POST["name"];
}
else
{
echo "Name is not set";
}
```

You should do this for all if your other **`$_POST`** variables before passing it to your `smtpmailer()`.

Answer (score 1):

Button Code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit">
```

and replace the code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$message=$_POST["name"]."\r\n".$_POST["email"]."\r\n".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n".$_POST["subject"]."\r\n".$_POST["message"];

smtpmailer('ali_n_claudiu@yahoo.com', 'mailinteraction@gmail.com', 'Improve Mediehus Aarhus', 'From contact form', $message);

}
```

TO

```
$message=$_POST["name"]."\r\n".$_POST["email"]."\r\n".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n".$_POST["subject"]."\r\n".$_POST["message"];

smtpmailer('ali_n_claudiu@yahoo.com', 'mailinteraction@gmail.com', 'Improve Mediehus Aarhus', 'From contact form', $message);
```

Comment: it worked flowless but I had another question about a pop-up message that I wish to display once the form is sent. I was using a JavaScript `if(!$mail->Send()){ 
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";
        }` at the end of smtpmailer function and it's not working, it doesn't display the pop-up.

Comment: try this if(smtpmailer('ali_n_claudiu@yahoo.com', 'mailinteraction@gmail.com', 'Improve Mediehus Aarhus', 'From contact form', $message)){  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('submitted successfully!')</script>";}

Answer (score 0):

Use **[isset](http://www.php.net/function.isset)** as @Shankar Damodaran said or

Try this if you want hide notice and errors.

> ini_set("display_errors","off");    //set it on if you want display errors

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])){
    $message=$_POST["name"]."\r\n".$_POST["email"]."\r\n".$_POST["phone"]."\r\n".$_POST["subject"]."\r\n".$_POST["message"];
    smtpmailer('ali_n_claudiu@yahoo.com', 'mailinteraction@gmail.com', 'Improve Mediehus Aarhus', 'From contact form', $message);
}
```

This way the email is sent only when the form is submitted